# Is is possible to install sharp for node.js without python?

Tags: node.js

I am needing to install `sharp` for node.js https://github.com/lovell/sharp but it appears that one of its dependencies (libvips) needs python (and so installation fails as I don't have python on my system and don't expect I'll be able to use python in my production environment).

I read that on the `sharp` github page it states "OS X, Windows (x64), Linux (x64, ARM) systems do not require the installation of any external runtime dependencies." so I'm not sure why I need python.

Comment: Which operating system are you using for development and production?

Comment: Windows 10 (x64) for dev and linux for production (heroku or something)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sharp` package uses node-gyp, which is a tool for "compiling native addon modules for Node.js." Typically native means C or C++ libraries like libvips. Python 2.7 is required for node-gyp to work as explained in [the install docs](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation). Despite `sharp` coming with prebuilt binaries, it still requires node-gyp (for now) as explained in [this issue](https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/458).

Answer (score 1):

Using version `0.26.x` of sharp seems to fix the issue now and doesn't require Python to install.
From their [changelogs](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/changelog):

> Prebuilt libvips binaries are now statically-linked and
> Brotli-compressed, requiring Node.js 10.16.0+.