# yarn install can't build sharp and fails

Tags: node.js, next.js, sharp, yarn-v2

I've updated Node and Yarn, but when I'm trying to run `yarn install` on my NextJS project, it throws this:

```
...
➤ YN0007: │ sharp@npm:0.29.3 must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed
➤ YN0009: │ sharp@npm:0.29.3 couldn't be built successfully (exit code 1, logs can be found here: D:\TEMP\xfs-6da33975\build.log)
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 0s 965ms
➤ YN0000: Failed with errors in 1s 538ms
```

I've got yarn v3.5.0 and Node v20.9.0

Here's a copy of my Package.json for more details

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.4.1",
    "@emotion/server": "^11.4.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
    "@fontsource/roboto": "^4.5.1",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.0.1",
    "@mui/material": "^5.0.2",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.8.4",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.8.1",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.32.0",
    "@types/echarts": "^4.9.12",
    "@types/lodash.clonedeep": "^4.5.7",
    "@types/react-color": "^3.0.6",
    "echarts": "^5.2.2",
    "echarts-gl": "^2.0.8",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "framer-motion": "^10.15.1",
    "i18next": "^21.2.4",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^6.1.2",
    "lodash.clonedeep": "^4.5.0",
    "next": "12.1.7-canary.4",
    "next-i18next": "^11.0.0",
    "next-seo": "^4.28.1",
    "next-sitemap": "^3.0.5",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-calendly": "^4.1.1",
    "react-color": "^2.19.3",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-i18next": "^11.12.0",
    "react-multi-carousel": "^2.8.0",
    "react-rnd": "^10.3.7",
    "react-use": "^17.4.0",
    "sharp": "^0.29.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^17.0.43",
    "@types/react": "17.0.25",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "eslint": "7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "11.1.2",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.6.2"
  }
}
```

The bug occurred when I upgraded Node and Yarn to latest versions

Comment: Can you share a copy of your package.json?

Comment: I've added it !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54409953/cant-install-sharp

I'm seeing a lot of people having difficulty installing sharp. Before you run in the first answer however, it might be a good idea to check out @EdieLemoine's answer as it could be a problem with your Python installation

Comment: Do i have to install the latest python as well? Even if it is a full NextJS project?

Comment: potentially - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987430/is-is-possible-to-install-sharp-for-node-js-without-python#:~:text=The%20sharp%20package%20uses%20node,explained%20in%20the%20install%20docs.

Can you see anything in your error logs?

Comment: Reinstalling Python helped me getting rid of the first error, but a second one appeared when i tried to launch the dev server

Comment: node:internal/process/esm_loader:40
      internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                                ^
Error: Qualified path resolution failed: we looked for the following paths, but none could be accessed.

Source path: D:\user\Documents\Developpement\project\website-v2\.yarn\cache\env-cmd-npm-10.1.0-85470635d6-efef550742.zip\node_modules\env-cmd\bin\env-cmd.js
Not found: D:\user\Documents\Developpement\project\website-v2\.yarn\cache\env-cmd-npm-10.1.0-85470635d6-efef550742.zip\node_modules\env-cmd\bin\env-cmd.js

Comment: What version of node are you using?

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue updating your Yarn version to V4.0.1 or down grade your node version to v16.16.0

Answer (score 0):

To those that come across this question and use an M1+ Mac:

#### My Initial Setup

- libvips v18.51 (installed with homebrew)
- node v20.11.0
- yarn v3.6.4

#### Error logs

```
sharp: Detected globally-installed libvips v8.15.1
sharp: Attempting to build from source via node-gyp
sharp: Found node-addon-api
sharp: Found node-gyp version 9.4.0
sharp: See https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install#building-from-source
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@9.4.1
gyp info using node@20.11.0 | darwin | arm64
gyp info chdir src
gyp info find Python using Python version 3.11.5 found at "/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.11/bin/python3.11"
gyp info spawn /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.11/bin/python3.11
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/redacted/Documents/dev/joplin/joplin/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/redacted/Documents/dev/joplin/joplin/packages/tools/node_modules/sharp/src/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/redacted/Documents/dev/joplin/joplin/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/redacted/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.11.0/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/redacted/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.11.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/redacted/Documents/dev/joplin/joplin/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/redacted/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.11.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/redacted/Documents/dev/joplin/joplin/packages/tools/node_modules/sharp/src',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/nothing/../../node-addon-api/nothing.o
  LIBTOOL-STATIC Release/nothing.a
warning: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: archive library: Release/nothing.a the table of contents is empty (no object file members in the library define global symbols)
  TOUCH Release/obj.target/libvips-cpp.stamp
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/sharp-darwin-arm64/common.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/sharp-darwin-arm64/metadata.o
../metadata.cc:233:46: error: no member named 'NewOrCopy' in 'Napi::Buffer<char>'
        info.Set("exif", Napi::Buffer<char>::NewOrCopy(env, baton->exif, baton->exifLength, sharp::FreeCallback));
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
../metadata.cc:236:45: error: no member named 'NewOrCopy' in 'Napi::Buffer<char>'
        info.Set("icc", Napi::Buffer<char>::NewOrCopy(env, baton->icc, baton->iccLength, sharp::FreeCallback));
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
../metadata.cc:239:46: error: no member named 'NewOrCopy' in 'Napi::Buffer<char>'
        info.Set("iptc", Napi::Buffer<char>::NewOrCopy(env, baton->iptc, baton->iptcLength, sharp::FreeCallback));
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
../metadata.cc:242:45: error: no member named 'NewOrCopy' in 'Napi::Buffer<char>'
        info.Set("xmp", Napi::Buffer<char>::NewOrCopy(env, baton->xmp, baton->xmpLength, sharp::FreeCallback));
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
../metadata.cc:246:31: error: no member named 'NewOrCopy' in 'Napi::Buffer<char>'
          Napi::Buffer<char>::NewOrCopy(env, baton->tifftagPhotoshop,
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
5 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/sharp-darwin-arm64/metadata.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/redacted/Documents/dev/joplin/joplin/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:203:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:518:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:294:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 23.3.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/redacted/Documents/dev/joplin/joplin/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--directory=src"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/redacted/Documents/dev/joplin/joplin/packages/tools/node_modules/sharp/src
gyp ERR! node -v v20.11.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.4.1
gyp ERR! not ok
```

#### What worked for me

- `brew uninstall vips`
- `yarn install` (yarn.lock can be found [here](https://github.com/laurent22/joplin/blob/8eea3953f3f2e91a1250e65f09770ea4d4ac3bea/yarn.lock))